# How to get a list of fields from a sharepoint list with microsoft-graph?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

How can I get the values of a `ListItem` from a SharePoint List via the .NET Graph SDK? I'm getting a "bad request" error.

```
var listItemData = graphClient
  .Sites["tenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/siteA:"]
  .Lists["List1"]
  .Items["117"]
  .Request()
  .Select("FullName,FirstName,Lastname")
  .GetAsync()
  .ResuIt;
```

When I use Graph Explorer I can fetch the fields but not from the SDK.

Is there a sample to get all ListItems and to print the field values to the console?

Comment: when i execute this with graph.explorer i can see the record

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs since the request returns [`ListItem` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0):

```
var listItemData = graphClient.Sites["tenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/siteA:"]
.Lists["List1"].Items["117"].Request()
.Select("FullName,FirstName,Lastname").GetAsync().Result;
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but the properties specified in select expression belongs to `ListItem.Fields` property

To return `ListItem` field values, either replace

```
.Select("FullName,FirstName,Lastname")
```

with

```
.Expand("Fields($select=FullName,FirstName,Lastname)")
```

For example:

```
var request = await graphClient.Sites[{site-path}].Lists[{list-name}].Items[{item-id}].Request().Expand("Fields($select=FirstName,FullName)").GetAsync();
```

Or specify [`FieldValueSet` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fieldvalueset?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint, for example:

```
var request = await graphClient.Sites[{site-path}].Lists[{list-name}].Items[{item-id}].Fields.Request().Select("FirstName,FullName").GetAsync();
```